# How to enable HTTPS in Superset when running locally

Tags: docker-compose, apache-superset

In order to integrate Superset with my application properly, I need to enable HTTPS. During development I'm running it with docker-compose. I couldn't find any useful information on how to do that. The version I'm running is v1.1.0

I'd be very glad if you could help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Clone superset repo

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/superset.git
```

add nginx-proxy as service in docker-compose.yaml

```
nginx-proxy:
      image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
      ports:
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - .certs:/etc/nginx/certs
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      environment:
         DEFAULT_HOST: superset.localhost
```

add VIRTUAL_HOST and WEB_PORTS for superset service in docker-compose.yaml

```
environment:
  CYPRESS_CONFIG: "${CYPRESS_CONFIG}"
  VIRTUAL_HOST: superset.localhost
  WEB_PORTS: 8088
```

Let's create self signed certificate for HTTPS.

```
mkdir .certs && cd .certs
```

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/OnnoGabriel/f717192ed92bf55725337358f4af5ab2/raw/9b669462299c9981bd7864901f09fc2885d9e780/create_certificates.sh

sudo chmod 700 ./create_certificates.sh 

sudo ./create_certificates.sh

enter-domain name --> superset.localhost
```

To make a browser familiar with our root CA, we have to import them into browsers.

Firefox --> https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008547993-How-to-Install-Securly-s-SSL-Certificate-in-Firefox-on-Windows

Chrome --> https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/206081828-How-to-manually-install-the-Securly-SSL-certificate-in-Chrome

take **rootCA.crt** file and add them into your browsers based on above instruction.

now start your superset docker instance by

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Now you can access superset by https://superset.localhost

For more details checkout this article

https://betterprogramming.pub/docker-powered-web-development-utilizing-https-and-local-domain-names-a57f129e1c4d

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me. I followed the steps successfully. However, now when I enter `https://superset.localhost` I face the Secure Connection Failed error (https://ibb.co/DYZSKzM). Could you help me with that too?

Comment: @RemoteEng Error message shown on the image will happen only if we didn't add VIRTUAL_HOST under the superset service. Kindly update them into docker-compose will resolve the issue. If you are using firefox use URL as https://superset.localhost/login/

Comment: `VIRTUAL_HOST` was already there. I'm using Firefox so I just tried `superset.localhost/login`, yet the same error is still there. I also followed your steps once again along with cloning the repo but it hasn't resolved the issue. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm still having issues. I couldn't get it to work on Firefox, however, got it to work on Firefox Developer Edition. Now there's no Firefox error. However, Superset responds with 502 Bad Gateway error. I think it has to do something with nginx proxy. To me it seems as if VIRTUAL_HOST: superset.localhost wasn't there but it actually is there. I attached screenshots of terminal errors below.
https://ibb.co/XJXSXcW
https://ibb.co/GHgSyQd

Do you know what could be wrong? Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @jagamts1, did you have a chance to check my comments above ( May 22)?
I am still waiting on your reply.
Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: Hey getting error - Unsupported config option for services.superset: 'VIRTUAL_HOST'

Answer (score -1):

For those who tried this solution and got stucked in 502 Bad Gateway. You have to put Superset and Ngix in the same network.
For exemple put this is all services in the yml file:
networks:
- backend_default

Comment: please take a look at the original question and keep it clean